# Paypal Payout Webhooks

Tags: paypal

I'm unable to find documentation by PayPal about how it handles webhooks for payouts. Are payouts treated the same as payments, so that a completed payout will initiate a payment completed webhook? In general, do payments and payouts translate to each other doing webhooks; or are there intricacies and gotchas someone from the paypal team could explain to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a webhook perspective, the payouts transactions and sale transactions are not exactly the same thing. The payout event will be added into the webhooks supported event type list but not yet at this moment.
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#event-type-support

So the classic IPN will still be your consideration of handling the "call-backs", for payouts and even other transaction types under RESTful API

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Is this still true? I want to implement a webhook for payout api payments also. Was hoping not to use IPN.

Comment: Do I need to subscribe all webhook events related to payouts ?

Answer (score 0):

Steps To work on payout:

- go to paypal developers account and login using business account
- Create new app and get client, secret etc
- create some personal accounts.

Go to https://github.com/paypal/Payouts-PHP-SDK to get sample code. Update your credentials and it will work.

If you want a running code, go to https://www.voizacinc.com/ and submit inquiry. You will get working code.